# print the value of a variable in Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, windows

In PHP I'm used to being able to do `print $var` or `print_r($var)`.

I can print variables in my views in python but they end up in my cmd window not on the page itself. This is fine for some things but windows' cmd window isn't exactly the most readable when it starts wrapping output and turning it into gibberish.

I tried doing `{% print somevar %}` in the django template, but I get TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'print'

So, for someone who's new to Python how do I easily see the value of a variable?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Is it for debugging, or is it just to use the value of a variable in the template?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
<html>
{{ this_is_my_variable_that_is_passed_to_my_view }}
</html>
```

the `{{` allow variable access to the item which will call the items `__unicode__`  function if it exists otherwise it will call its `__str__` function

Comment: Ah, I knew there'd be something so basic. There isn't by any chance a lib or something that can print large dicts in a more readable format with expanding/collapsing is there?

Comment: not off hand ... its a good idea though there may be a template tag for it somewhere on the interwebs

Answer (score 9):

`{{ your_variable }}` will print the value.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#basics