# Django: return a StreamingHttpResponse on an existing html page

Tags: html, django, django-views, streaming, httpresponse

Since it is better to have a single question for each issue, be patient if is similar to another part of [another my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921085/django-passing-value-from-form-to-view-without-saving-into-database) related to the same project.

The situation:

I have a form on html in which I can set a number and when it is submitted, it is call `views.stream_response` which pass the value to *stream.py* and it returns a *StreamingHttpResponse* and   "virtual" blank browser page appears (*/stream_response/*) in which I can see a progressive number every second up to `m` :

```
   1
   2
   3
   ..
   m
```

**stream.py**

```
import time

def streamx(m):
    lista = []
    x=0
    while len(lista) < m:      
        x = x + 1
        time.sleep(1)
        lista.append(x)
        yield "<div>%s</div>\n" % x 
        print(lista[-1])    
    return (x)
```

**---UPDATE---**

**views.py**

```
def stream_response(request):   
    test = InputNumeroForm()   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test = InputNumeroForm(data=request.POST)
        if test.is_valid():
            m = test.cleaned_data['numero']     
            print (test)      
            print("m = ", m) 
            #resp = StreamingHttpResponse(stream_response_generator(m))
            resp = StreamingHttpResponse(stream.streamx(m))
            return resp               
        return render(request, 'homepage/provadata.html',{'user.username': request, 'test': test}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^homepage/provadata/$', views.provadata),    
url(r'^stream_response/$', views.stream_response, name='stream_response'),
...
```

**homepage/provadata.html**

```
<form  id="numero" action="/stream_response_bis/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{test}}                                
    <input type="submit" value="to view" />
</form> 

//{{ris}}
```

I tried to do a render_to response to stay on *homepage/provadata.html* and to see the progressive lists but *stream.py* does not starts and I can see only the input number *m* on the command line.

I tried with [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116881/django-streaminghttpresponse-into-a-template) suggestion in **views.py**

```
def stream_response_generator(m):    
    ris = stream.streamx(m) 
    yield loader.get_template('homepage/provadata.html').render(Context({'ris': ris}))
```

(adding `{{ris}}` to template and
`resp = StreamingHttpResponse(stream_response_generator(m))` in *stream_response* function)
but I obtain on the template:

`<generator object streamx at 0x0000000004BEB870>`

And on command line it prints the input value but it not pass anymore the parameter to stream.py.

So.. **How can I solve this issue?**

Comment: did you look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922874/how-to-stream-an-httpresponse-with-django

Comment: @ger.s.brett Yes, but it points (like in my case) into a "not physically existing" html page... I don't know how explain this in a clearer way.

Comment: if you want to use ajax - why do you need the stream at all?

Comment: In many answers or comments I saw that people refer to ajax... so I tried with it but I think that for my purpose StreamHttpResponse is the solution. I'am new in programming and probably there are many things that I don't know, so I asked here for some help.

Comment: Have you solved you question ? Do you need a proper answer ?

Comment: No, I did not solved yet.

Comment: stream.py is not correct - there is syntax error (you can't have return with value in generator). So it seems that you did not publish question correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the StreamingHttpResponse to indicate that you want to stream results back and all the middleware that ships with django is aware of this and acts accordingly to not buffer your content output but send it straight down the line.

You can disable the ETAG middleware using the condition decorator. That will get your response to stream back over HTTP. You can confirm this with a command-line tool like curl. But it probably won't be enough to get your browser to show the response as it streams. To encourage the browser to show the response as it streams, you can push a bunch of whitespace down the pipe to force its buffers to fill. Example follows:

```
from django.views.decorators.http import condition

@condition(etag_func=None)
def stream_response(request):
    resp = HttpResponse( stream_response_generator(), mimetype='text/html')
    return resp

def stream_response_generator():
    yield "<html><body>\n"
    for x in range(1,11):
        yield "<div>%s</div>\n" % x
        yield " " * 1024  # Encourage browser to render incrementally
        time.sleep(1)
    yield "</body></html>\n"
```