# Issues querying form data using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to do something real simple (so I thought), but having some problems a couple hours of research has failed to resolve.

Simply put I'm trying to take 2 form data entries(using Flask-WTForms) and query the values entered against a table.  A basic search function.

I've managed to get to the point that I can see SQLAlchemy running **A** query, just not having any luck with it and triggering the rollback().

```
2016-01-27 03:27:39,127 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2016-01-27 03:27:39,128 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT "Motor"."Asset Tag" AS "Motor_Asset             Tag", "Motor"."Horsepower" AS "Motor_Horsepower" 
FROM "Motor" 
WHERE "Motor"."Asset Tag" AND "Motor"."Horsepower"
2016-01-27 03:27:39,128 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2016-01-27 03:27:39,129 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
```

Here are some code snippets.

View:

```
@app.route('/searchassets', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def searchassets():
    form = SearchAssetsForm()
    results = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            asset_tag = form.asset_search.data 
            horsepower = form.horsepower_search.data
            results = Motor.query.filter(Motor.asset_tag, Motor.horsepower).all()
        except:
            db.session.rollback()
            flash("Error.")
        return render_template('searchassets.html', form=form, results=results)
return render_template('searchassets.html', form=form, results=results)
```

Form Model:

```
class SearchAssetsForm(Form):
asset_search = StringField('asset_search')
horsepower_search = IntegerField('horsepower_search')
```

Template:

```
{% extends "basehead.html" %}
{% block content %}
<center>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Search Asset Attributes Below</h1>
  <br>
  <form action="" method="post" name="submit">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  <p>
    {{ form.asset_search(placeholder=" Enter Asset Tag") }}
 </p>
 <p>
     {{ form.horsepower_search(placeholder=" Enter Horsepower") }}
 </p>
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
<br>
<table>
<th> </th>
<th>Asset Tag</th>
<th>Horsepower</th>
<tr>
    <td>{% print(results.asset_tag) %}</td>
    <td>{% print(results.horsepower) %}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a *bare `except` clause* that is making the debugging a guessing game. At least, temporarily remove it and see what the actual error is. Or, log the exception and the traceback.

I think you are not using the checks in the [`filter()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) correctly, should not it be:

```
Motor.query.filter(Motor.asset_tag == asset_tag, 
                   Motor.horsepower == horsepower).all()
```

Or, in case you want [`filter_by()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by):

```
Motor.query.filter(asset_tag=asset_tag, 
                   horsepower=horsepower).all()
```

Comment: You were right, it was incorrect syntax on my end.  I thought because I specified the Motor model at the beginning of the query it would associate the argument objects on its own. But now I see it had no way of knowing why it should associate the `asset_tag`  object with it's `asset_tag` column.  A lesson in poor variable choices! I thank you very much.

One other quick question; When I change my template formatting to `<td>{% print(results) %}</td>` It successfully prints the data objects just not the column values. I'm guessing my `print(results.asset_tag)` is looking in the wrong place too?

Comment: Don't call `print` in your templates. Use `{{ results }}` instead. The reason `results.asset_tag` doesn't work is that `results` is a list. You need to iterate over it. `{% for result in results %}{{ result.asset_tag }}{% endfor %}`.

Comment: Thanks for the input - I actually had it iterating over before I ran into the query syntax problems and I took it out. Popped it back in and everything is working great(ish). One question though; is there a reason `{{ text }}` is considered better practice than  `{% print(object.data) %}`? Just curious.

Comment: @xGlorify from what I recall, there is no print function inside the templates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848286/print-the-value-of-a-variable-in-python-django. Thanks.